# How do I make installed software available to all users of a computer?

Tags: windows-vista, user-profiles, delphi

I installed Embarcadero Delphi software on Windows Vista. Later I had to delete the profile of the user account with which I installed Delphi. I created a new profile for myself, but now I cannot use Delphi anymore.

Is there a way to make Delphi available without reinstalling it?

Answer (score 0):

I could access the Delphi executable file in

```
C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\bin\bds.exe
```